# The endpoint status of my Amazon Aurora dababase clusta is in a creating state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I converted my Aurora serverless1 database cluster to a provisioned cluster. While the database cluster status is in the 'available' state the endpoint status is still in the 'creating' state.

Below is the conversion command used.

aws rds modify-db-cluster 
--db-cluster-identifier devcluster 
--engine-mode provisioned 
--allow-engine-mode-change 
--db-cluster-instance-class db.t3.large

Below is the error from the log and event tab;

error restarting MySQL: failure running with monitoring lock

How do I resolve this? Any help will be appreciated.